# mysql connection always die

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am very new to programming and have been watching youtube videos along with reading many books to familiarize myself with some of the components to programming. I watched TimKipp tutorial on youtube,PHP Series - Building A PHP MySQL Forum Tutorial Series Part, in regards to making a login page with php/mysql. I  feel I have done everything identical from setting up the database to all of the programming. With all that being said, when I log into the form with the username/password that I created, the mysql die function is always alerting me. I can not find where I went wrong. Also, I am using MAMP 
This is the login page script

```
    <?php session_start();  ?>




    <html>
    <head>
    <title> untitled/title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="wrapper">
    <h2>timkipp tutorial</h2>
    <p> basic login page</p>

    <?php
        if  (!isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
        echo "<form action='login_parse.php' method='post'>
        Username: <input type='text' name='username' /> &nbsp;
        Password: <input type='password' name = 'password' /> &nbsp;
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' />
        ";
        } else {
          echo "<p> You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['username']."  &bull; 
              <a href='logout_parse.php'> Logout</a></p>";
        }
        ?>

        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

And this is what I use to connect to the database

```
         <?php
             $host = "localhost" ;
             $username = "root" ;
             $password = "" ;
             $db = "tests" ;

             mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Just keep going");
             mysql_select_db($db);

         ?>
```

If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great. Thank you in advance

Comment: What's your session timeout limit? Could you share your `phpinfo()` results?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: You should change the `die` to `die(mysql_error())` - the database will tell you why it had an issue.

Comment: And you should probably find a new tutorial as the mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed from PHP in future versions. Find one that shows how to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: I changed the connect.php to add "die(mysql_error());" and the result was Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO), in myphpadmin I have not password assigned. My phpinfo is as follow from the php.ini file: max_execution_time = 30     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 32M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your connection

```
     <?php
         $host = "localhost" ;
         $username = "root" ;
         $password = "" ;
         $db = "tests" ;

         $connect = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Could Not Connect To The Server");
         $db_sel = mysql_select_db($db, $connect) or die("Could Not Select The Database");

     ?>
```

Comment: I tried doing that and it was an error, "Could Not Connect To The Server"